# VB6: Remaining time class

Tags: class, math, vb6

I always wanted a simple system that would show me how many minutes approximately are left while processing a long for-next-statement.

I tried do achieve this by creating a class.

At the start, I want to set how many for-nexts I have (-> setMax)
At each For-Next, I will tell the class that one of the for-nexts was done. (->addOneDone)
The class would then tell me how many minutes I still have to wait until the entire for-next-statement will be done.

I was pretty sure I made that quite ok, but something is still wrong.
I suspect it is the milliseconds to minutes conversion.

Would anybody try to help me find my mistake?

Thank you very much!

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private m_lMax&
Private m_lItemsDone&
Private m_lStart&
Private m_cMillisecondsAlreadyNeeded As Currency
Private m_lMinutesLeft&
Private m_lLastTick&

Public Sub setMax(ByVal uCount As Long)

    m_lMax = uCount

    m_lStart = GetTickCount()

End Sub
Public Sub addOneDone()

    m_lItemsDone = (m_lItemsDone + 1)

    Dim lTick&
    lTick = GetTickCount

    Dim lMillisecondsNeeded&
    lMillisecondsNeeded = (lTick - m_lLastTick)

    If (m_lLastTick > 0) Then

        m_cMillisecondsAlreadyNeeded = (m_cMillisecondsAlreadyNeeded + lMillisecondsNeeded)

        Dim lMillisecondsForOneItem&
        lMillisecondsForOneItem = (m_cMillisecondsAlreadyNeeded / m_lItemsDone)

        Dim lItemsLeft&
        lItemsLeft = (m_lMax - m_lItemsDone)

        Dim cMillisecondsLeftToBeDone As Currency
        cMillisecondsLeftToBeDone = (lMillisecondsForOneItem * lItemsLeft)

        Dim lMinutes&
        lMinutes = MillisecondsToMinutes(cMillisecondsLeftToBeDone)

        m_lMinutesLeft = lMinutes

    End If

    m_lLastTick = lTick

End Sub
Private Function MillisecondsToMinutes(ByVal uMilliseconds As Long) As Integer

    Dim seconds As Double
    seconds = uMilliseconds / 1000

    Dim minutes As Double
    minutes = seconds / 60

    MillisecondsToMinutes = minutes

End Function
Public Property Get MinutesLeft() As Long

    MinutesLeft = m_lMinutesLeft

End Property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my code, and it works now:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private m_lMax&
Private m_lItemsDone&
Private m_lStart&
Private m_cMillisecondsAlreadyNeeded As Currency
Private m_lMinutesLeft&

Public Sub setMax(ByVal uCount As Long)

    m_lMax = uCount

    m_lStart = GetTickCount()

End Sub
Public Sub addOneDone()

    m_lItemsDone = (m_lItemsDone + 1)

    Dim lTick&
    lTick = GetTickCount

    Dim lMillisecondsNeeded&
    lMillisecondsNeeded = (lTick - m_lStart)

    Dim dblMillisecondsForOneItem As Double
    dblMillisecondsForOneItem = (lMillisecondsNeeded / m_lItemsDone)

    Dim lItemsLeft&
    lItemsLeft = (m_lMax - m_lItemsDone)

    Dim cMillisecondsLeftToBeDone As Currency
    cMillisecondsLeftToBeDone = (dblMillisecondsForOneItem * lItemsLeft)

    Dim lMinutes&
    lMinutes = MillisecondsToMinutes(cMillisecondsLeftToBeDone)

    m_lMinutesLeft = lMinutes

End Sub
Private Function MillisecondsToMinutes(ByVal uMilliseconds As Long) As Integer

    MillisecondsToMinutes = uMilliseconds / 1000 / 60

End Function
Public Property Get MinutesLeft() As Long

    MinutesLeft = m_lMinutesLeft

End Property
```

Comment: Just out of interest, won't the calling of this routine distort the amount of time left? (Obviously only negligibly, but still...)

Comment: Yeah, sure. But for me it does not matter.